# Checking if a number is triangular

Tags: prolog, triangular

So i have this predicate triangular(N) in which N is a number and this predicate return true if a number is a triangular number.

My problem is this for some reason my predicate does an infinite loop instead of just summing the numbers until the N.

Example:

?- triangular(3).
3
true

and it doesnt end.

So basically this is priting the sum of numbers until 3 but its doing something i dont understand.

Program:

```
triangular(N) :- triangular(N,0).

triangular(N,AC) :- triangular(N,AC,N).

triangular(N,AC,0) :-  write(AC).

triangular(N,AC,CONT) :- NCONT is CONT - 1,
                         NAC is AC + NCONT,
                         triangular(N,NAC,NCONT).
```

Answer (score 0):

### Background infomation

Prolog can search for more than one solution to your query.

Consider this program:

```
human(alice).
human(bob).
```

When you query `?- human(X).`, Prolog will search for assignments for `X` that match your program. It will show you the solution `X = alice`. Afterwards you can either stop searching by pressing `.` or continue searching by pressing `;`. If you continue, Prolog will then find `X = bob`. Afterwards it will stop because it has exhausted all possible solutions:

```
?- human(X).
X = alice .

?- human(X).
X = alice ;
X = bob.
```

You can control the search process using the cut predicate `!`. The cut predicate cuts off alternative paths in the current layer. So if you extend the above program with this rule:

```
find_first_human(X) :- human(X), !.
```

Running the query `?- find_first_human(X).` will only only output `X = alice.`, without searching for further answers. Prolog knows that the `human(X)` can be resolved in multiple ways, but then the `!` tells Prolog to ignore those alternatives.

### Applying this to your program

The main problem is that your last `triangle` predicate does not require `CONT > 0`. So when you query `?- triangle(3).`, Prolog eventually arrives at `triangular(3,3,0).`, which matches your `write` rule. As you can see, your program outputs `3` as expected. However, Prolog then sees that there are alternatives solutions for `triangular(3,3,0)`, so it offers you to continue searching. You can stop by pressing `.`, or continue by pressing `;`. If you continue, Prolog will try the last rule for `triangular`, with `CONT` being resolved to `0`. Thus `NCONT` becomes `-1`. This will then go into an infinite loop, where the last `triangular` rule is applied repeatedly, decrementing `CONT` with no end.

You can verify this by using `trace.` (can be disabled again with `notrace.`):

```
?- trace.
?- triangular(3).
   Call: (8) triangular(3) ? creep
   Call: (9) triangular(3, 0) ? creep
   Call: (10) triangular(3, 0, 3) ? creep
...
   Call: (13) triangular(3, 3, 0) ? creep
   Call: (14) write(3) ? creep
3
   Exit: (14) write(3) ? creep
   Exit: (13) triangular(3, 3, 0) ? creep
...
true ;
   Redo: (13) triangular(3, 3, 0) ? creep
   Call: (14) _2076 is 0+ -1 ? creep
   Exit: (14) -1 is 0+ -1 ? creep
...
```

You can stop this by changing the last rule to:

```
triangular(N,AC,CONT) :- CONT > 0,
                         NCONT is CONT - 1,
                         NAC is AC + NCONT,
                         triangular(N,NAC,NCONT).
```

This forbids Prolog from applying the rule for `triangular(3,3,0)`.  When you run the query `?- triangular(3).` with the modified program, Prolog should then write out the `3` as before when arriving at `triangular(3,3,0)`. Afterwards it detects that there could be alternative solutions. If you press `;`, it then detects that the last rule cannot be applied because the `CONT > 0` constraint does not hold. It then stops searching:

```
?- triangular(3).
3
true ;
false.
```

We can further simplify this with the cut predicate `!` shown in the previous section, by modifying the `write` rule to:

```
triangular(N,AC,0) :-  write(AC), !.
```

This tells Prolog to not search for alternative solutions to `triangular(3,3,0)`. When you run the query `?- triangular(3).`, Prolog should then write out the `3` as before, and then exit without further search:

```
?- triangular(3).
3
true.
```